# QGIS 2.2 Identify tool highlight settings

Tags: qgis

Does anyone know how to change the highlighting settings of Identify tool in QGIS 2.2?
I mean, when i click on a feature with the Identify tool, the feature gets highlighted in red. Can i change it to, lets say, blue?
And where are the highlighting settings settings stored?

W. regards,

Edit- i add a screenshot of the Options|Map Tools window. No Identify tool highlighting there...
[image]

Comment: Probably they implemented the option in qgis 2.4

Comment: Thanks for your quick responses.
Probably this is a new feature, but unfortunately i need a solution for qgis 2.2. I suppose it's possible, somehow.

Comment: Could I ask why you want this? Are you looking to add this to Print Composer or to make screenshots?

Comment: I want to validate feature attributes and compare features visually. Using the Identify tool, i get the feature attributes and a highlighted feature on the map canvas in one go. 
I can check if the highlighted feature overlaps or intersects any other features. 
Sometimes i compare 2 specific features, then i select one and identify the other and get 2 differently highlighted features.
I was hoping that if i could change the highlighting settings for Identify tool as for the selection tool, i could get a better visual comparison.

Answer (score 5):

In Settings -> Options -> Map Tools -> Highlight color you can set the color for the highlighting tool. (Works in Qgis 2.4)

In Project -> Project Properties -> General you can find the Selection color.

Comment: Could I ask which version of QGIS are you using? I cannot find the option to change the **highlight** colour in QGIS 2.2.0

Comment: I use 2.4 but i thought that this option should be the same. You can find the options in Settings

Comment: Nope :) I'm guessing this is a new option in 2.4 or was part of a nightly build for 2.2 but still it's good to know that it can be changed.

Comment: In 2.4 there is a "Identify" field where you can set e.g. the search radius and the buffer.

Comment: Ahh that's cool, I will be checking out the new features in 2.6 when it comes out this month :)