# Select features tool- QGIS 2.14

Tags: features, select, color, qgis-2.14, outline

When i select polygon with select tool- the whole polygon colored:

[image]

[image]

i seek a way to select the shape only with outline, as it possible in ArcGIS. I know i can change the opasitiy in "Map Tool" but this isn't a solution for me.

i red [QGIS 2.2 Identify tool highlight settings](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118073/qgis-2-2-identify-tool-highlight-settings/118076#118076) but didn't found an answer.

Is it possible with QGIS?

Comment: Perhaps this answer works http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/174664/set-selection-color-transparent-and-border-color-red-in-qgis-using-python.