# QGIS auto-highlight identify results feature with style defined

Tags: qgis, style

I am wondering about the option of highlighting one field in the Identify Results panel by linking the styling applied to the layer, as you can see below.

[image]

I would like to have that cell highlighted in colour, which would depend on the value inside.

Is that possible at all?

I found some link here:

[https://www.cadlinecommunity.co.uk/hc/en-us/articles/360013744878-QGIS-Change-Identify-Results-Colour#:~:text=By%20default%2C%20when%20you%20use,of%20your%20choice%20%E2%80%93%20e.g.%20purple](https://www.cadlinecommunity.co.uk/hc/en-us/articles/360013744878-QGIS-Change-Identify-Results-Colour#:%7E:text=By%20default%2C%20when%20you%20use,of%20your%20choice%20%E2%80%93%20e.g.%20purple).

but the website doesn't respond at all

I found something also here:

[QGIS 2.2 Identify tool highlight settings](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118073/qgis-2-2-identify-tool-highlight-settings)

but it looks like it applies to the things highlighted in the panel by myself.

I need something auto-highlighted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i know, you can't set conditions on Highlight or Selection color, it's either all yellow, all red, all blue...
depending on the color you choose in the settings

You can set an attribute form with a specific style that reproduce your classification

[image: Attribute form]

For example, if the field *id_gri* has a value over 1000, i set a blue color and under 1000, a green color. Then, with the identify tool set to open the form each time a single entity is selected, I get a window with the corresponding color.

[image: Identify window]

Comment: What version of QGIS do you have? I cannot see the style section in the 3.12 version.

Comment: 3.16.9, the style section appears on a container (created with the green + button)

Comment: That explains everything then. I will accept your answer because I believe it's correct. Thank you for your effort.